# How do i get every json elemet in a json file and put them in an array

Tags: java, arrays, json

```
[
  {
    "origin": "12345",
    "destination": "2345",
    "time": 37,
    "days": "37",
    "people": "45"
  },
  {
    "origin": "34562",
    "destination": "12341",
    "time": 28,
    "days": "27",
    "people": "99"
  },
  {
    "origin": "84532",
    "destination": "35521",
    "time": 40,
    "days": "17",
    "people": "39"
  },
  {
    "origin": "12312",
    "destination": "75435",
    "time": 17,
    "days": "17",
    "people": "35"
  },
...
]
```

I want to get every json object in the json file and put them in a array.
So i need an "origin" string array, "destination" string array, "time" int array, "days" string array and a "people" string array.

I started like this because of the '[' and tried a lot of things to get the every element but i am not able to get every element in the json.file

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        File file = new File(dirPath + "move.json");
        try {
            String content = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(file.toURI())), "UTF-8");
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(content.substring(4));
```

Thank you

Comment: I don't know what are you trying with `content.substring(4)`. Use a Json parser like `gson` or `jackson`.

Comment: use JSONArray instead of  JSONObject and remove substring, and iterate JSONArray you will get desired output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, you have to create a map, the keys of the map are the keys in you JSON objects.
And while iterating in your JSON Array, you append each key value to the map you have already created

```
public class App 
{
    public static void main( String[] args ) throws Exception
    {
        File file = new File("input.json");
        String content = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(file.toURI())), "UTF-8");
        JSONArray array = new JSONArray(content); //parse your string data to JSON Array
        Map<String, List<Object>> map = new HashMap<>(); //create a HashMap having a key type as String and values as List of Object, 
        //since you are creating array for each key
        for(int i=0; i<array.length(); i++) //looping on all JSON Objects
        {
            JSONObject obj = array.getJSONObject(i);
            for (String key : obj.keySet()) { //looping on all keys in each JSON Object
                if(map.get(key) == null)
                    map.put(key, new ArrayList<Object>()); //initializing the list for the 1st use
                map.get(key).add(obj.get(key));//adding the value to the list of the corresponding key
            }
        }

        //Output:
        for (String key : map.keySet()) {
            System.out.println(key);
            System.out.println(map.get(key));
        }
    }
}
```

And the output will be :

```
origin
[12345, 34562, 84532, 12312]
destination
[2345, 12341, 35521, 75435]
days
[37, 27, 17, 17]
time
[37, 28, 40, 17]
people
[45, 99, 39, 35]
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Exactly what I needed.